# WinRT - set pointer position

Tags: windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, win-universal-app

I'm writing Windows Universal app in C# and I'm wondering if it is possible to set pointer position programatically. Of course if PointerDeviceType is Touch or Pen, this is rather impossible and irrelevant, but in case when user runs my App on desktop, such a possibility would be useful to me. There is globally accessible property Window.Current.CoreWindow.PointerPosition but it is read-only, and I haven't found anything similiar.

So, to sum up, is it possible in to set pointer position programatically in Windows Store App in case when pointer corresponds to mouse cursor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The latest Insider builds of Windows 10 have a settable `CoreWindow::PointerPosition`. It will also be in the final SDK.